# WP CRON jobs keeps on running indefinitely as now on AWS

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

Recently we had problems with the CRON jobs in WordPress, the timezone wasn't matching so we changed the timezone of the server. What happened as the result was that most of the CRON's next_run_relative was set to run NOW and they kept on running indefinitely.

Is there a way other than rebooting the instance (Because it is attached to the load balancer instance) to solve this? Below is an example

```
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------+
| hook                                            | next_run_gmt        | next_run_relative    | recurrence    |
+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------+
       |
| woocommerce_cleanup_logs                        | 2020-11-09 15:31:12 | now                  | 1 day         |
| woocommerce_cleanup_sessions                    | 2020-11-09 18:31:12 | now                  | 12 hours      |
| woocommerce_scheduled_sales                     | 2020-11-09 19:00:00 | now                  | 1 day         |
```